# Exercise 10 in section 11, chapter V, Conway's functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-compact-groups, almost-periodic-functions

On page 163, section 11, chapter V, Conway's functional analysis.

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $f\in\mathrm{C}_b(G)$. We say $f$ is **almost periodic** if
> \begin{equation}
> \mathcal{O}_f\,\colon\!=\text{closure of }\left\{f_x\in\mathrm{C}_b(G)\colon x\in G\right\}
> \end{equation}
> is compact in $\mathrm{C}_b(G)$, write $f\in\mathrm{AP}(G)$.

**My question:** I want to show if $G$ is not compact, then the only function in $\mathrm{AP}(G)$ having compact support is the zero function.

But I have no idea.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: @Yuval Peres yes